# Lost my phone, how can I get my contacts from my SD card?

Tags: contacts, sms, hardware, lost-phone

Well, I lost my phone. I know I can get some contacts from google, but it's not phone numbers, only e-mails. (I already tried locating my phone with google, and I was able to do it. It seems to be turned off now, though.) Is there any way that I can get those contacts from my SD card? I can get a new phone, but I can't get all those contacts back.

Answer (score 0):

Did you back up the contacts to you SD card before losing the phone? Normally the contacts are stored on the phone's internal storage, or sometimes on the SIM card.

If you did save the contacts to the SD card before losing it, you should be able to retrieve you contacts by going to your contacts app, and finding the option *'Import/Export'*, where you can choose *'Import from SD card'*.

Answer (score 0):

NO..If you have not backup it to SD card or if you did not backup it using some 3rd party app to your email or drive. there is no way to retrieve that. But next time you can use some backup app there are all over the play store not only contact it can backup every thing in your phone.